# Creating a toggling conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, addclass

I have two if statements like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(function() {
    var titleClass = $('.title').hasClass('title-left');
    if (titleClass = true) {
        $('.title').removeClass('title-left');
        $('.title').addClass('title-move');
    }
    var titleMove = $('.title').hasClass('title-move');
    if (titleMove = true) {
        $('.title').removeClass('title-move');
        $('.title').addClass('title-left');
    }
},1000);
});
```

However the classes do not add or remove. Should I use a different conditional?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (titleClass = true) {
```

You are not comparing values but assigning it. This is what you should do:

```
if (titleClass == true) {
```

**EDIT:**

Also the code in `if (titleMove == true) {}` will be executed always when `(titleClass == true)`, since the class `title-move` was added by the code before it. So if it has class `title-left` it is changed to `title-move`, and right after that it will be changed back to `title-left` and it may seem like nothing happend.

I think this may be what you want:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(function() {
    var titleClass = $('.title').hasClass('title-left');
    if (titleClass == true) {
        $('.title').removeClass('title-left');
        $('.title').addClass('title-move');
    } else {
        var titleMove = $('.title').hasClass('title-move');
        if (titleMove == true) {
            $('.title').removeClass('title-move');
            $('.title').addClass('title-left');
        }
    }
},1000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: While it works, I don't know why. Do you know where I can find documentation about that?

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out you should compare with `==` operator not assign with `=`.

As further improvement you can make use of [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method to reduce amount of code:

```
setInterval(function () {
    $('.title').toggleClass('title-left title-move');
}, 1000);
```